# is it wise to create separate app for admin pages in react?

Tags: reactjs

For normal functions, I think it is okay to incorporate all pages in to one react app using routes.

But when it comes to admin page, I think it is wise to create a separate react app which will compile into a different .js bundle and serve this not though react route but a totally different html along with the separately created js bundle.

I think if we bundle admin and normal functions into one file and serve through react router, there is a risk where the client can look into the js file and decipher admin pages. Couldn't this be a security risk?

If I'm overthinking please let me know. Other feedbacks are also welcome

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that whatever backend is serving your React application has properly-implemented authentication, it's not *technically* a security flaw; a malicious actor can't negatively affect your product purely based on the admin page source being bundled with everything else.

That said, it does make it easier to see how your admin tools work, and gives someone nefarious a good indication of where they need to look for exploits.

Personally I'd never serve up a consumer-facing application and admin-facing application in the same codebase. Even though it's not exploitable directly, it makes it easier to find a potential exploit. Security through obscurity is largely a fallacy, but it never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lazy loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html), not to send whole pages in one bundle. but if they are totally different with no functional overlap, it's better to separate them, better responsibility separation, cleaner git history, etc ... And unless you are not exposing valuable data like hard coding api key, reading js source isn't a problem. The security breach happens in the back- servers and the back end services should be using some sort of authentication to respond, check [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/), [OpenID](https://openid.net/what-is-openid/) workflow. Its a very common pattern and used by tech giants.